# How to get value of the data at a particular location of a smart contract deployed on RSK?

Tags: rpc, rsk

I would like to obtain info particular smart contract - that is deployed on the RSK Testnet - to get the data values from its storage. How can I do this?
I'm using `eth_getStorageAt` JSON-RPC, but i'm getting unexpected results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do this, you do indeed use the `eth_getStorageAt` RPC request.
Here's an example:

```sh
curl \
  -X POST \
  -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
  --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getStorageAt","params":["0x19f64674d8a5b4e652319f5e239efd3bc969a1fe", "0x1", "latest"],"id":1}' \
  https://public-node.testnet.rsk.co/
```

This will yield the following response

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 1,    "result":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000033b2e3c9fd0803ce8000000"
}
```

How it works - the `eth_getStorageAt` RPC takes 3 params:

- `ADDRESS`  - an address string of the smart contract
- `STORAGE_POSITION` - a hexadecimal string for the position in the storage of the smart contract
- `BLOCK_PARAMETER`  - a hexadecimal string of the  integer block number for  values at specific blocks, or the string `latest` for the latest value

The last parameter (`BLOCK_PARAMETER`) is interesting, as you can use it to query historical values, and see how the data at that location within the storage changes over time, for example.